# How can I style invalid text field content in Spring MVC (JSP)

Tags: spring-mvc, validation

The Spring MVC JSP tag library has a tag  for rendering form errors. This makes it easy to render an error message next to, say, an input text field. However, it is common practice on many websites to also style the input text field itself (with a red border maybe) to highlight a validation error.

Is there any way of doing this with the Spring JSP tags or will I have to bake my own solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used Spring MVC JSP tags but looking at the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html) it looks like `cssErrorClass` is the way to go:

```
<form:input path="userName" cssErrorClass="error"/>
```

> Equivalent to "class" - HTML Optional Attribute. Used when the bound field has errors.

Obviously you can now define `input.error` class in your CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Thank for this - I will read the docs more carefully in the future :)

Comment: This is on JSP side. I have to modify something on controller side to handle if exist an error or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spring:bind` tag around the `form:input` tag. In between the `spring:bind` tag you can use something like `${status.error ? 'error' : ''}` for your style class.

`status.error` will be true if errors. `form input` field is available