# Populating The Error Field in a JSP with an Error From Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

This is more of a broad question, but I'm working on some form validation functions in Javascript.  Instead of using alerts I have been told to use the error fields in the JSP, but where ever I look for information on form validation it simply shows an alert being thrown.

So if I have something like this to check for only letters in a name field

```
 function allLetter(inputtxt)  
  {   
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
  if(inputtxt.value.match(letters))  
  {  
  alert('Your name have accepted : you can try another');  
  return true;  
  } 
  else  
  {  
  alert('Please input alphabet characters only');  
  return false;  
  }
```

Then I want to use the

```
  <form:errors path= "firstName"/>
```

to throw the error that the function is getting whether that means the field is blank or a number has been entered, but how do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use form:errors tag in JSP, you should do server side validation.

I think in your question you refferred to using client side javascript validation right?

Here is a similar example showing server side validation and form:errors within JSP:

[Spring Validator - show errors using <form:errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980750/spring-validator-show-errors-using-formerrors)

Comment: I spent the whole day yesterday researching this issue, and came up blank. I have a working validator in my back end. If a field is empty or incorrect it will come up with the proper error. 

My challenge here is to write to this error field using a function in javascript.

After hours of research all I can find is either using document.getElementsByID and use that to get to the Inner HTML and  put it adjacent to the field that way, or else use an alert.  I am not supposed to use either. Apparently, there is something in the JS similar to what I  can do in the validator, but I can't see it.

Comment: HI jack, It could be that I am not following your request. Here's my thought - if all you are trying to do is to put the error mssage adjacent to the input field, you could accomplish this via JSP or even form tag. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249553/how-can-i-style-invalid-text-field-content-in-spring-mvc-jsp

Comment: I am trying to use the form error tag, but I'm trying to use a JavaScript function ton populate that tag.

Comment: So if say he function is triggered by an improperly formatted email address the Js function will update the form error tag in the html not the validator